# Jquery code doesn't work on html created items

Tags: jquery

check this https://jsfiddle.net/qh2pfhjy/

I am create a div on the fly but click function doesn't work.

Any idea?

Also my code is:

```
$("#helloDiv").click(function(){
    alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
});

$(document.body).append('<div id="helloDiv">Edit me</div>');
```

Comment: use $("#helloDiv").on('click',function(){ for dynamically created elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bind events to dynamically created elements, update code like this.

From

```
$("#helloDiv").click(function(){
    alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
});
```

To

```
$(document).on("click", "#helloDiv", function(){
    alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
});
```

Make sure you replace `document` by whatever *parent context* you have that is a) not dynamically created and b) as close as possible to your dynamically added div.

For reference - http://api.jquery.com/on/

https://jsfiddle.net/qh2pfhjy/2/

Comment: I wouldn't exactly apply that handler to `document` which is a first-class performance sin. Using on makes sense, but instead of `document` use the nearest available parent that's not dynamic.

Comment: So if i am create dynamicly items inside body what i need to know so can work?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @IreneT. - If you have elements dynamically getting added as direct child of body, then you should use document.